# Zookeeper / Exhibitor cluster nodes keep restarting

Tags: docker, cluster

I have successfully deployed 3 Zookeeper / Exhibitor nodes in Docker containers and they form a cluster. I am starting them via

```
java \
-jar /opt/exhibitor/exhibitor.jar \
--port ${EXHIBITOR_PORT} --defaultconfig /opt/exhibitor/defaults.conf \
--configtype s3 --s3config ${S3_BUCKET}:${S3_PREFIX}  --s3configprefix ${S3_PREFIX} \
--s3region ${AWS_REGION} --s3backup true --hostname ${HOSTNAME} \
${SECURITY}
```

and have set

```
auto-manage-instances=1
```

There are `myid` files for all the nodes and each node knows about all the other nodes in the cluster. However, when I start them, they constantly keep restarting. Any ideas what might be causing this? There is no error log or whatsoever, just each zookeeper node starts and then after a while restarts.

Comment: Can you share your zoo.cfg?